# how to restore default text input look with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

You can see in the picture of the two text input boxes (Firefox 52)
That the top one is the default appearance and the lower one has
changed after:

```
document.getElementById("answerBox").style.background = "white";
```

Do I have to recreate the element in order to get the default appearance back
or there an easier way?
[image: text inputs]

Thanks for any help,

Gerard

Comment: try changing `border` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to fully understand your question, but to restore a default appearance you can do something like this :

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var input = document.getElementById('input');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input.classList.toggle('border');
});
```

```css
input.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<label>Your answer</label>
<input id="input" type="text" />

<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

The "classList.toggle('border')" add the border class to the input classList if not exists, and delete it if already exists.